# How to implement evanescent text in Emacs?

Tags: templates, emacs

Some word processing software (e.g. Apple Words) has the interesting feature of supporting *evanescent text*.

This kind of text is used as placeholder in template files: if I start a new *Report* from a template, some entries are filled with *evanescent text* which disappears when text is inserted within the region corresponding to the text or its boundary.  This text is also identified with a special appearance.

How can I implement *evanescent text* in Emacs, if at all possible?  It might be enough to support it in rich-text or markdown buffers.

Comment: Are yasnippets enough?

Comment: @abo-abo Can you tell me more about yasnippets?  I found official documentation which lacks a description of the purpose of the software.

Comment: True. Have a look at this screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOj7btx3ATg

Comment: @abo-abo I do not find this screencast very helpful, isn't there some feature list or purpose description of that software?  (BTW I do not see the point to describe an installation procedure before giving one the chance to decide if the software is at all useful.)

Comment: To make things short, it gives you a repository of templates that you can expand in any buffer by name, e.g. "i" could expand to "include". These templates usually have placehoders that you can fill in.

Comment: @abo-abo, I believe the OP is searching for something more like the placeholder text introduced in HTML5. For example, Stack Overflow's search box contains the text "search" in light grey. But when you click into the box and type, "search" disappears, as if it was never there. Is this correct, OP?

Comment: @Chris This is *absolutely* correct. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following snippet might give you an idea.

```lisp
(defun remove-evanescent (oldpos newpos)
  "We need that later on to remove evanescent text. We could also remove the superfluous space here."
  (remove-text-properties newpos
              (next-property-change newpos)
              '(display nil point-entered nil)))

;; An elisp-snippet to be tried in the *scratch* buffer:
(insert (propertize " " 'display "Help"
            'point-entered 'remove-evanescent))
```

Comment: There is actually a nice smell in there! I have to study it a bit more because I am still unfamiliar with text properties. Thank you!